# Is following correct example of Deadlock in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

i   want  deadlock  situation using  two threads ...

```
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("b4 join" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("after join" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());

    t.start();

    t1.start();

}
}

   output

   b4 joinThread-0
   b4 joinThread-1
```

and  program goes on running..never  execute  2nd println.. i am not  sure  is this correct 
example of deadlock or  not ? could any  one put lights  on this..if  it  is  not correct one  how  to  deadlock using  two threads in java..( can`t say newbie to java but  for thread i am  always..)

Comment: Technically, yes, this is a deadlock, because `Thread.currentThread().join();` waits for the current thread to die and therefore will never return normally. It just isn't a very interesting one, because it doesn't involve a second thread.

Comment: @Alex  what  does it mean 'it doesn`t involve a second thread'..my  thinking is current  thread(suppose t) will  give change  to   second thread  t1..which  execute upto line of 'join' method..and gives chance to   first thread  t1 and  this  goes on ..is my assumption is  correct ?

Comment: What I mean is, you could remove `t` and `t1` altogether and just put the call to `Thread.currentThread().join();` directly in the `main` method and your program still wouldn't terminate.

Comment: public static void main(String... a)
{
Thread.currentThread.join();
}